# Tried to come up with a novel sorting algorithm on my own

Tags: algorithm, sorting, rust

As said in the title, I tried to come up with a sorting algorithm on my own to practice.

It seems to work, even though it's not in place. Is it "new" or does it already exist?

```rust
fn salmo_sort(v: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    let mut c = v.clone();

    for i in 0..v.len() {
        let mut contatore = 0;
        let mut n = 0;
        for x in 0..v.len() {
            if v[i] > v[x] {
                contatore = contatore + 1
            } else if v[i] == v[x] {
                n += 1
            }
        }

        for t in 0..n {
            c[contatore + t] = v[i]
        }
    }

    *v = c;
}
```

I know that I could use generics instead of hard-coding `i32`.

Apart from that, how can I improve this? Is there someway to make it in-place?

Comment: Looks like [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: …an inefficient version of counting sort. Counting sort is O(n), this one is O(n^2).

Comment: For a beginner, I love the ingenuity! +1